# Analytics API Call Request Limits

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Our client is hitting their API call quotas for Analytics and trying to troubleshoot with their Dev team.

How can we help the client access their daily usage number to understand how much they are exceeding their quota?

Answer (score 0):

The Google API console, which apparently has been renamed to "[Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/)", displays usage information in the API&Services-Section of your project.